# MVVM and classes within classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to get my head around MVVM and don't know how to model the following.

Suppose a real-life situation where an entity contains zero to many other entities.

In MVVM the model could then be a class A which for example as a member has a list ListOfC of objects of class C. So for example (without constuctor code etc):

```
public class A {
  public ObservableCollection<C> ListOfC { get; }
  public int SomeMemberD { get; }
}

public class C {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Now how do I get a view model that will notify the view for all changes to the data?

I can build a class AVM which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, no problem there. Since ListOfC is defined as an ObservableCollection, I get notified if I change the list. 
Then I could create a class CVM implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, so for example (without notification code, constructors etc.):

```
public class AVM : A, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  // ListOfC is member of AVM inherited from A 
  // but is a list of C, not CVM
}
public class CVM : C, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  // Inherits Name and Enabled from C
}
```

What I would like to achieve is that when Name or Enabled of C are changed, the UI shows the changes. What I have is a listview which binds to a list of A and shows all items (works), and a second list view that per selected item in the first list view should show a list of C with the values of Name and Enabled. This list shows and is updated when the first list's selection changes, but if Name or Enabled are changed from the backend, the second list is not updated.

How do I get from the A to C relationship in the model to a AVM to CVM relationship in the view model without actually maintaining a list of C in A and a list of CVM in AVM that need to be kept synchronised? Surely there is an easier way? It's almost as if I would like to 'cast' the ListOfC in A to a ListOfCVM in AVM, if you know what I mean...

Comment: You shouldn't derive your VM from a M.  M should implement INotifyPropertyChanged too. You don't have different VMs just to suit a M, rather you have a VM per V.   A single V and corresponding VM might be pulling in data from multiple Ms

Comment: Ah, maybe that's what I am struggling with: M should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If that's the case I can solve my problem (by having both A and C implement INotifyPropertyChanged). I thought from what I've read so far that the M is a lean data model separated from the VM, but that would still be the case when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, which I didn't realise.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` provides an event `PropertyChanged` Occurs when a property value changes. So you could subscribe to `ListOfC.PropertyChanged +=(event)=> doyouroperation`

Comment: Yes, the M is lean but only so far as it shouldn't include business logic. That doesn't apply to `INotifyPropertyChanged` as it predates WPF and it's not really business logic

Answer (score 1):

MVVM is a software architecture pattern used to separate development.

Per Wikipedia:

> Model refers either to a domain model, which represents real state content (an object-oriented approach), or to the data access layer, which represents content (a data-centric approach).
>
> As in the MVC and MVP patterns, the view is the structure, layout, and appearance of what a user sees on the screen (UI).
>
> The view model is an abstraction of the view exposing public properties and commands. Instead of the controller of the MVC pattern, or the presenter of the MVP pattern, MVVM has a binder. In the view model, the binder mediates communication between the view and the data binder.[clarification needed] The view model has been described as a state of the data in the model.

In short:

- **Model** - contains data
- **View** - user interface that the user interacts with
- **ViewModel** - performs the logic of the application

Typically, each `View` (xaml file) has an associated `ViewModel` (cs file). The reason why is because the `ViewModel` will handle the logic for its associated `View`, rather than making the `View` perform the crunching behind-the-scenes (xaml.cs file). The benefits of doing so are that 1. it is less intensive on the `View` itself, and 2. separation of development, which makes testing specific components, among other things, easier.

The entire idea of MVVM revolves around the idea of data binding. In other words, as mentioned before, each `View` has its associated `ViewModel`. It is **bound** to that `ViewModel` (the `ViewModel` is set as the `DataContext` of the `View`), so that the `ViewModel` can perform the crunching.

Here is an example to help you grasp the concept:

> You have an application that has one `View`, and the `View` simply contains one text box and one button. The user can enter text into the text box, and when the button is pressed, the text changes within the text box to remove all vowels from the inputted text. So, if the user enters "hello world!" and presses the button, the text box will change from "hello world!" to "hll wrld!"
>
> Behind the scenes, what happened is that the `ViewModel` has a property called MyText, which is a string. As the user typed into the text box (in the `View`), the property (in the `ViewModel`) changed accordingly. When the user pressed the button, the handler method (in the `ViewModel`) that is hooked to the button's `Click` (in the `View`) is what will look at the MyText property and perform the vowel removal. Once the MyText property's value is changed from "hello world!" to "hll wrld!" the text box in the `View` automatically reflects this change, since the binding would be **two-way** binding.

In order to achieve such a binding, the `View` code (xaml) for the text box would look something like:

```
<TextBox Name="Mytextbox" Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and somewhere else (either in the `View` xaml or the `View` xaml.cs (behind the scenes), the DataContext would be set:

```
MyViewModel _viewModel;

public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    DataContext = _viewModel;
}
```

I hope this helps to clear your confusion, and hopefully you can apply these concepts to the specific application you are trying to wrap your head around.

Comment: Great explanation, but this was the part I did understand. As specified above I missed the part where the model can implement INotifyPropertyChanged too. Thanks for the effort though, it might help others.

Comment: Nice explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

Just as MickyD said in his comment, model class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That model is lean is only because model should not ontain any use case–specific or user task–specific behavior or application logic for best re-usablity. [This article from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) has a vary detailed discussion about class responsibilities and characteristics in MVVM pattern. Maybe it will help you have a better understanding with MVVM.

Comment: I actually read that article but it misses a hands-on example in my opinion. But luckily SO helps out.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to achieve is that when Name or Enabled of C are changed, the UI shows the changes

For this to work, the backend or the model must notify the outside world of the change. The most common way for it to do this is to raise an event, like for example the `PropertyChanged` event of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

If the model doesn't raise any event whenever it's state is being modified, the only way for someone else (like for example a view model or a view) to find out whether it has actually been modified will be to check the values of the model's properties and compare them to the latest known values at regular (poll) intervals. This is an ugly solution compared to listening for events.

So in this case it sounds like your model classes should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If they provide any other way to notify observers that their state has changed, you will need to wrap the model class in view model classes that do implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and bind to these view model classes in your client application. This is because WPF only knows about how to subscribe to property (state) changes for objects that implement this particular interface.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to ensure that V and M stay synchronized:

1. M implements INotifyPropertyChanged - as mentioned above, this allows VM to expose classes from M directly to V; otherwise, VM must subscribe to M's PropertyChanged events and generate its own PropertyChanged events for V.
2. VM knows when M changes - this is particularly relevant for editors that have the sole ownership of the instances of M that are being shown in V. In this case, every action performed on M by VM must raise the appropriate PropertyChanged events.
3. Changes to M are handled through other events / notifications. One example is that all changes to a given property B of class A in M is performed by a single class BofAUpdater, which sends out notifications whenever B is changed on any instance of A. Depending on the situation, this can reduce the task of subscribing to all the required events / notifications.